# boost::hash_value inline function for exported C++ class

Tags: c++, boost, dll, shared-libraries, inline

So I'm implementing a `boost::hash_value` override for my class that is exported from a shared library.  I'd like to have that `hash_value` function available for everyone who uses this class.  Currently my hash_value function is exported and defined in the cpp file, even though it just calls an inline member of my class.  Instead, I'd like this hash_value function to also be inlined as to avoid unneeded function calls.  Currently the header's like this:

```
#ifdef MYDLL
#define MY_API __export
#else
#define MY_API __import
#endif

class MY_API MyGUID
{
public:
     ...
     inline size_t Hash() const
     {  return m1 ^ m2; }
     ...
private:
     size_t m1,m2;
};

namespace boost
{
    // Defined in .cpp file; just returns inGUID.Hash();
    MY_API size_t hash_value(const MyGUID &inGUID);
}
```

But I'd like that hash_value to be more like:

```
   namespace boost
    {
        // I'd like to inline this, like so:
        static inline size_t hash_value(const MyGUID &inGUID)
        { 
             return inGUID.Hash();
        }
    }
```

Except this code above defines hash_value in every .cpp file that includes it, quite likely littering the binary, and is ugly in principle.

Putting aside the question of whether the function calls make a measurable difference in performance, how can I get my class' Hash function inlined for clients of this shared library that use MyGUID in hashed containers like ordered_set?

I suspect it involves templates, but I couldn't quite figure out how.

Comment: You don't need both `static` and `inline`, as `inline` kind of implies `static`.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  static is file-local scope, and without it, the function is getting globally redefined in every cpp file that includes it, so it causes linker collisions ('symbol previously defined').  Static makes it locally defined for every cpp file, so being defined in multiple files won't cause a linker collision, but it's ugly and takes up space in every file.

Comment: @vercellop what is "file scope"?? C++ compiler works with each translation unit, i.e. cpp, separately. It doesn't now that your header file was included in other cpps as well.

Comment: @IgorR, yes, I mean that static functions' linker visibility is limited to a single cpp file.

Comment: @vercellop static function visible in *every* cpp where it's #included. But it has internal linkage, and thus doesn't visible to the linker.

Comment: Right, that's why I called it "ugly and takes up space in every file," referring to every object file where it was included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside `boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp` you will see that hash_value for existing types are defined like:

```
inline std::size_t hash_value(bool v)
{
    return static_cast<std::size_t>(v);
}
```

If boost already uses technique this is your hint that it is safe for you to do the same! Regarding your concern about inefficiencies of using `inline` in the header file, that is precisely how it is designed to be used and since your function is simply forwarding to another function call it will probably lead to no increase in code size at all.

Unless you are going to be doing something very fancy with preprocessor directives it does not make much sense to use `static inline`, i.e., if you just need one version of this function just mark it as `inline`.